# Sympy evalf for real symbol

Tags: python, sympy

This Sympy code works as I expect:

```
>>> x = sp.Symbol("x")
>>> y = sp.Symbol("y")
>>> z = sp.Symbol("z")
>>> (x+y+z).evalf(subs={"x":1, "y":2, "z":3})
6.0
```

However, if I use real-valued Symbols instead, the expression isn't simplified:

```
>>> x = sp.Symbol("x", real=True)
>>> y = sp.Symbol("y", real=True)
>>> z = sp.Symbol("z", real=True)
>>> (x+y+z).evalf(subs={"x":1, "y":2, "z":3})
x + y + z
```

I was unable to find an explanation for this by searching with keywords like `sympy symbol real evalf` - I only get unrelated results.

Why isn't the expression simplified in the second case? How can I substitute in values for real-valued Symbols and evaluate the expression?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Interesting question! I didn't have a ready answer and I had to try a few things to figure out what's going on. For future reference, though, please note that this is **not a discussion forum**; we want questions to [get to the point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) and not discuss yourself but only **the code** (but it is a good idea to explain *why* each example is being shown, and highlight the important features). Ideally we also want questions that are asked explicitly. I [edit]ed the question to show good style. For more guidance, see [ask].

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you very much for helping me editing, you made my question become more clear! It's really a good example for me to follow how to ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the symbols as keys for the dictionary of substitutions, rather than string names:

```
>>> (x + y + z).evalf(subs={x: 1, y: 2, z: 3})
6.00000000000000
```

There appears to be an inconsistency between how complex and real symbols are treated:

```
>>> x = sp.Symbol('x')
>>> x.subs(x, 1)
1
>>> x.subs('x', 1)
1
>>> x = sp.Symbol('x', real=True)
>>> x.subs(x, 1)
1
>>> x.subs('x', 1)
x
```

I can't find anything relevant about this in the documentation, and the built-in help text isn't useful either. My best guess is that a string `'x'` is naively converted using `sp.Symbol`, and the resulting symbol is always a complex-valued symbol that doesn't match the real-valued one with the same name.

I would consider this behaviour a bug and file a bug report (or look for an existing report). IMO, if a string is usable at all, it should match any symbol with that name; and an expression shouldn't be able to contain two different variables with the same name and different types; and trying to substitute in a variable with a matching name and incompatible type should probably raise an exception:

```
>>> x = sp.Symbol('x')
>>> # why allow this?
>>> broken = sp.Symbol('x', real=True) + x
>>> broken # if the types matched, it would simplify to 2*x
x + x
>>> # surely 2 is the only value that makes sense?
>>> broken.subs('x', 1)
x + 1
>>> x.subs('x', 1)
1
>>> # If this is allowed at all, surely the result should be 1?
>>> x.subs(sp.Symbol('x', real=True), 1)
x
```

Comment: This is explained in the docs: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/assumptions.html#gotcha-symbols-with-different-assumptions

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate how Sympy docs try to "humanize" the information, but I'm not a fan of how it's organized.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin and @ KarlKnechtel, many thanks for the help. I tried it and successfully solve the problem.

Comment: There is a lot of work going on to expand and reorganise the SymPy docs at the moment. Feel free to open a GitHub issue or start a discussion on the mailing list with suggestions for improvement.